# Limiting number of cells in UITableView

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift

So, I have a UITableView nested inside a TableViewController.
I have set two sections.

The first one has 7 static rows

The second one has 4 static row.

The first section of rows stops at 7 and then goes onto the next section.
But the second section seems to go forever past the 4 cells outlined in the attributes inspector.

Anyway to stop that?

Answer (score 2):

Place an empty UIView as the tableViewFooter. There are two ways to do so:

1. Via InterfaceBuilder:
   Drag a UIView onto the bottom of the UITableView, then set its height to 0 in the size inspector.
2. Via Code:

In your custom class for your TableViewController create the empty UIView and set it as the tableFooter:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

Both methods suppress the empty lines on your tableView.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is by using Grouped Table Views.  With a Grouped table view each section has space between but also the last row will be the last row!

For those using storyboards this can be achieved by changing the Style attribute to Grouped.